# Do latter keys in an hash assignment from an array always override earlier keys?

Tags: perl, associative-array

Given this:

```perl
%h = (a => 3, b => 4, a => 5);
```

Imperically `$h{a} == 5` holds true, but are there cases where `$h{a} == 3` because of internal dictionary hashing or some other perl-internal behavior?

Another way to ask: Does perl **guarantee** to keep key-ordering  the same when assigning an array to a hash, even in the event of a key collision?

Duplicates key entries are convenient for things like `%settings = (%defaults, %userflags)` so I can hard-code defaults but override with user supplied flags.

Comment: Good question.  Whatever is guaranteed or not, I wouldn't want to rely on that order

Comment: Another curious "update hash" method: `@settings{ keys %user } = values %user`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can rely that the assignment list will be evaluated left to right as surely as you could rely on an assignment to an array occurring in the correct order.

```
sub DebugHash::TIEHASH { bless {}, shift }
sub DebugHash::CLEAR { %{shift} = (); }
sub DebugHash::STORE {
    my ($tied, $key, $value) = @_;
    print STDERR "STORE '$key' => '$value'\n";
    $tied->{$key} = $value;
}

tie %hash, 'DebugHash';
%hash = (a => 'first', a => 'second', a => 'third',
         a => 'fourth', a => 'next', a => 'last');
```

---

Output:

```
STORE 'a' => 'first'
STORE 'a' => 'second'
STORE 'a' => 'third'
STORE 'a' => 'fourth'
STORE 'a' => 'next'
STORE 'a' => 'last'
```

Answer (score 0):

key-ordering in a hash appears quite random.  That is you cannot guarantee that the hash when dumped or looked at will be in the same order as you assigned it (a => 3, b => 4, a => 5); it could be displayed as ( b => 4, a => 5).

Also, there are only two key values in your hash the collision simply overwrites the first:

```
use Data::Dumper;

my %h = (a => 3, b => 4, a => 5);

print Dumper(\%h);
$VAR1 = {
          'a' => 5,
          'b' => 4
        };
```

It took me only three tries to produce:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'b' => 4,
          'a' => 5
        };
```

Updating as @mob mentioned left to right is what I would assume the second (or nth) assignment of a value to a key will replace the previous value.  In this case you are replacing the whole hash the left to right ordering would result in a hash with two elements the value of any duplicates would be the last key/value encountered.

Comment: You said "That is you cannot guarantee that the hash when dumped or looked at will be in the same order as you assigned it" --- I know, thats not the question, in both cases of your example a=>5. My question is about assignment: do latter key entries in the origin array override earlier key entries in the origin array when assigned to the destination hash?  Could `a` ever be 3?

Comment: Maybe I overlooked where you said "there are only two key values in your hash the collision simply overwrites the first".  Is this behavior guaranteed in-array-order?  If so, then that answers the question.

Comment: You misread the OP's question.

Comment: I would assume a left to right order for assignment.  But then if I was initializing (or replacing) a hash I would never have a duplicate in the initialization/assignment.

Comment: @KJ7LNW never thought of that use case in the context of this question.  Not sure if I have used it taht way but I must keep that in mind.